# Which of the recently launched Starlink satellites is the coated one?

Tags: starlink

Does anybody of you experts know which of the recently launched Starlink satellites is the coated one?

We are occasionally measuring their brightness and would like to compare uncoated vs. coated.

Thank you.

Comment: Third one from the left? The dimmer one? At least they show up in the satcat as 2020-001A through BM (44914-44973)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the NORAD database, it is 71130 / STARLINK-1130 and has the additional designation DARKSAT.  Or as 2020-001BL.

https://celestrak.org/NORAD/elements/supplemental/table.php?tleFile=starlink

**update:** 2020-001BL (DARKSAT) is now 44932. For an explanation for why the number is now in the 40,000's rather than the 70,000's see answers to [Why is the NORAD Catalog number of SpaceX's Starlink's “Darksat” both 71130 and 44972?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40892/12102) and then note that the "DARKSAT" name is now assigned to `2020-001U  44932  STARLINK-1130  (DARKSAT)`

Comment: I've just asked [Why is the NORAD Calatog number of SpaceX's Starlink's “Darksat” both 71130 and 44972?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40892/12102)

Comment: Both the famous [Thierry Legault](https://youtu.be/6E_qyAyvugA) and [Celestrak](https://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/supplemental/table.php?tleFile=starlink) has  DarkSat as 020-001U (44932) STARLINK-1130 (DARKSAT) https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubGnW.png

Comment: I've made an **update** edit but you may want to clean this up further.